# Invert scrolling direction in browser

Tags: javascript, browser

I tried to do it using `onwheel`-event like this:

```
event.preventDefault();
$('#myDiv').scrollTop -= event.deltaY;
```

But there are two issues with the code:

1. it works in chrome but in firefox scrolling is unnatural (as far as I know firefox use smooth scrolling by default and my code breaks it)
2. I want to invert scrolling not only for mouse but for keyboard too

**added**: that is not similar to [the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling) question because I want the scrollbar to move the opposite direction.

Comment: Just FYI, I would throw my monitor across the room if I visited your website to find that behavior :) But seriously, why not `onscroll`?

Comment: Don't worry. I'm just working on a kind of a hack. Before invert events I also invert scrolling block and internal block (using css) so it will look regular for clients.

Comment: > "why not onscroll"   - show me an example, please. maybe this is the solution

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse Scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: you would bend the minds of people visiting your website.

Comment: > "Why would you want to do this?" - I'm solving problem with server rendering. I don't want to scroll my chat to the last message every time the server renders it. To do this I invert scrolling block horizontally (and the block inside it as well), so visitors will not even notice the changes.