# Can I make the browser window start at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, position, screen, viewport

Normally, when a page loads, the browser window starts at the top of `html` and `body`, something like this:

```
 ______________________________
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
 _______________________________
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- BOTTOM OF CONTENT -------
```

**CSS**

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
```

And then you have to scroll down to see the rest of the content.

---

Is there a way I can manipulate the CSS to make the browser window start at the bottom? Like this:

```
 ----- TOP OF CONTENT ----------
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ----- OUT-OF-VIEW CONTENT -----
 ______________________________
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
| BROWSER WINDOW BROWSER WINDOW |
 _______________________________
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reverse Scrolling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling)

Comment: @Himmel I don't believe that's a valid solution. That answer reverses what the scrollbar does, and the scrollbar still starts at the top. I want the scrollbar to behave normally but start at the bottom.

Comment: There are options using javascript, but css-only will be difficult.

Comment: Joe this is by far not the solution, but it could be a workaround if you want. Just throw the `window.scroll(x, y)` into the body tag onLoad. I chose a large `y` number, but this could work. obviously not CSS. `<body onLoad="window.scroll(0, 5000)">`

Comment: @m69 How could I do it with js?

Comment: @JoeMorano look at my original comment, that is JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
function scrollBottom() {window.scrollTo(0, 99999);}
if (document.addEventListener) document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", scrollBottom, false)
else if (window.attachEvent) window.attachEvent("onload", scrollBottom);
```

```html
content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>
content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>
content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>
content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>
content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>content<BR>
```

Comment: Beware that there's nothing preventing any element from getting taller than 99999 pixels. A more elegant way imo would be to do something similar to this: `document.body.scrollTop = document.body.clientHeight;`

Comment: That's true; I just wanted to keep it as simple as possible, and I thought the OP could judge which number would be right in his particular case. On the other hand, ridiculously long pages usually start out as only a few screens long, and then expand as you get to the bottom, like Google image search or facebook.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the answer of m69 didn't work for me. The following did.

```
function toBottom()
{
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
}
window.onload=toBottom;
```