# How to change the direction of mousewheel scrolling on an HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

Is there a way to use Javascript or jQuery to change the direction of scrolling on an HTML page (with mouse wheel) from up to down -> left to right?

Comment: Pls look around before asking. Here is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling

Comment: @Mr.Web That question seems to be about changing scrolling from up->down to down->up, not from up->down to left->right as is being asked for.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister I see. I'm sorry, I think I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a short function that makes your document scroll horizontally instead of vertically using the mousewheel:

```
$(function() {
   $("html, body").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 30);
      event.preventDefault();
   });
});
```

You will need to include the [jquery.mousewheel.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.min.js) script in your page for it to work.

Working JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/1zugp6w6/1/

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/)

Comment: @mohamadjavidi My bad, you need to include the mousewheel plugin [jquery.mousewheel.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel/master/jquery.mousewheel.min.js) for this to work.

Comment: believe me that's not working on Firefox and internet explorer it work on chrome and safari

Comment: @mohamadjavidi It would be helpful if you edit your question so we can see your specific case (in an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: your answer is correct but its not working on 2 browser

Comment: @mohamadjavidi My apologies for the code not working in Firefox - it looks like the demo is wrong. [Here is a working version](https://jsfiddle.net/1zugp6w6/1/) (also edited into my answer).

Comment: is there any way to still do this with vanilla JS?

Comment: @oldboy Try the `scroll` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll_event

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('html, body, *').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
        this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

that work for all browser