# Infinite scrolling after applying reverse scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, reverse

First of all, I am sorry for multiplying questions about reverse scrolling. I know that there are many answers out there, but after many hours of research and tries, I am still not able to implement this info my own website.

As you can see in the title, after applying reverse scrolling I can infinitely scroll my website, which leaves me with unwanted result. Here is an example to give you a good look at my problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.right').css('transform', 'translate3d(0,' + $(this).scrollTop()*2 + 'px, 0)'); 
  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
}
.outside {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.left {
  top: calc(100% - 48px);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  width: calc(50% - 16px);
}
.right{
  bottom: calc(100% - 48px);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  width: calc(50% - 16px);
}
.shot {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.shot_gap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}
.release {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outside">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="release"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="release"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Oryginaly `.shot` class will not have set `height` - I will throw some images inside this div - same amount and dimensions of images for `.left` and `.right` div.

Anyway, looking at the example, elements should have stopped after reaching similar position to the starting one. To force it, I've included `.release` class. Unfortunately, this is not the case in the example - it works but after deleting `.right` class from html, so I guess the problem here is javascript?

I was trying to mess with this solution:
[Reverse Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling) but I failed to implement this into my project.

I do not expect anyone to solve my problem. It would be nice if someone could point me in the right direction. For example, letting me know what is exactly wrrong, because I am still not sure if it's about line `bottom: calc(100% - 48px)` in `.right` class or maybe it's just the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I did this. It works but I am not happy about how I've actually achieved this. After research, I've discovered that parent must be set on `position: fixed`, because without this, div elements, move in oposite directions from each other making my page indefinitely long while scrolling - at least this is how I understand this. Unfortunetaly I could not just chage the `position` of my `.outside` class, because then I would lose the ability to scroll website at all. So the only possible way to make this work, was to created new wrapper on top of `.outside` with position set to `fixed`.

**EDIT:** It is possible to have only one wrapper with position `fixed`. It requires from you to get the total height of `.left` class and apply it to `.body`.

```
var totalHeight = $(".left").css("height");
$("body").css("height", totalHeight);
```

**End of EDIT**

This time I've used a little different js code - this helped me a lot: [Reverse Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling)

Here is the new version:

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function(){
    $(".right").css('bottom',$(window).scrollTop()*-1);
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.outsideL {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.outsideR {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.left {
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 48px;
  width: calc(50% - 64px);
}
.right{
  bottom: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 48px;
  width: calc(50% - 64px);
}
.shot {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000;
}
.shot_gap {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 48px;
}
.release {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 48px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outsideR">
  <div class="right">
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="release"></div>
  </div>
</div>
 
<div class="outsideL">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="release"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="shot_gap"></div>
    <div class="shot"></div>
    <div class="release"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```