# how can I Make the website (reverse mouse scrolling) in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, scroll, mouse, reverse

I want to scrolling from bottom to top in reverse mouse scrolling in wordpress website. 
is there any plugin?
script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery, please check the below example,

may be the duplicate of this question

[Reverse Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20776045/reverse-scrolling)

Comment: want it in wordpress,